# RichTextBox places linefeeds into Run element text property

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'd like to be able to paste text directly into a RichTextBox control while preserving tabs, line-feeds and new-lines.

Unfortunately, when pasting text from the clipboard (Ctrl-V), '\r' characters are being placed into the Text property of a Run element instead of being translated into a `<LineBreak />` element.

So, given the pasted text:

> Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et
>   expedita distinctio.
>
> Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis
>   est eligendi optio cumque nihil
>   impedit quo minus id quod maxime
>   placeat facere possimus, omnis
>   voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor
>   repellendus.

and...

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbNoteText" BorderBrush="Gray" xml:space="preserve" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="30,0,30,30" FontSize="14"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />



private void btnSaveNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbNoteText.Xaml)) {

string contents = rtbNoteText.Xaml;

}                
}
```

the contents of rtbNoteText.Xaml is:

```
<Section xml:space=\"preserve\" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste=\"False\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">
    <Paragraph FontSize=\"14\" FontFamily=\"Portable User Interface\" Foreground=\"#FF000000\" FontWeight=\"Normal\" FontStyle=\"Normal\" FontStretch=\"Normal\" TextAlignment=\"Left\">
    <Run Text=\"Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. \r\rNam libero tempore, cum         soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.\" />
</Paragraph>
</Section>
```

`rtbNoteText.Replace("\r","<LineBreak />")` won't do the trick because the line feeds are embedded within the Run element Text Property.

Is there a standard approach to get to this instead?:

```
<Section>
  <Paragragh>
    <Run>...</Run>
    <LineBreak /><LineBreak />
    <Run>...</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a Paragraph object manually by adding a  object for each line of your text and  when ever a line break is needed. You can split your text to lines using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

Below is an example:

```
string text = "Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.\r\r" +
                "Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod\r" +
                "maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.";

// I guess this how you are updating the textbox right now
//richTextBox.Selection.Text = text;

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();            
string[] lines = text.Split(new char[] {'\r'});
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = lines[i] });
    if (i < lines.Length - 1) paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
}
richTextBox.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

it should return you the following xaml via richTextBox.Xaml property:

```
<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
   <Run Text="Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio." />
   <LineBreak />
   <Run />
   <LineBreak />
   <Run Text="Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod" />
   <LineBreak />
   <Run Text="maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus." />
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you...  I'm actually reading the text out of the richtextbox control using 'richtextbox.Xaml' and then saving it off to a file.  So by that time, the Xaml property has already been populated with the carriage returns inside the Run element.